# How do I insert and echo birthday dropdown values

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am building the edit page for a users profile on my site. I am using codeigniter and am having trouble knowing what to use where as well as what to do for inserting the birthday drop down menus from my form helper. I also am not sure what I currently have is correct.

Additionally I am wanting to echo the value of what the user selected per field  so it's saved when they come back to edit their profile again.

Here is the code from my helper that creates the drop downs:

```
function month_dropdown($month="month", $top_months=array()) {
    $months = array(
            "choose"=>"Month",
            "----------",
            "Jan"=>"Jan",
            "Feb"=>"Feb",
            "Mar"=>"Mar",
            "Apr"=>"Apr",
            "May"=>"May",
            "Jun"=>"Jun",
            "Jul"=>"Jul",
            "Aug"=>"Aug",
            "Sep"=>"Sep",
            "Oct"=>"Oct",
            "Nov"=>"Nov",
            "Dec"=>"Dec"
    );

    $html = "<select name='{$months}'>";
    if(!empty($top_months)){
        foreach($top_months as $value){
            if(array_key_exists($value, $months)){
                $html .="<option value='{$value}'>{$months[$value]}</option>";
            }
        }
        $html .="<option>----------</option>";
    }
    foreach($months as $key => $month){
        $html .="<option value='{$key}'>{$month}</option>";
    }
    $html .="</select>";
    return $html;

}

function day_dropdown($day="day", $top_days=array()) {
    $days = array(
            "choose"=>"Day",
            "----------",
            "1"=>"1",
            "2"=>"2",
            "3"=>"3",
            "4"=>"4",
            "5"=>"5",
            "6"=>"6",
            "7"=>"7",
            "8"=>"8",
            "9"=>"9",
            "10"=>"10",
            "11"=>"11",
            "12"=>"12",
            "13"=>"13",
            "14"=>"14",
            "15"=>"15",
            "16"=>"16",
            "17"=>"17",
            "18"=>"18",
            "19"=>"19",
            "20"=>"20",
            "21"=>"21",
            "22"=>"22",
            "23"=>"23",
            "24"=>"24",
            "25"=>"25",
            "26"=>"26",
            "27"=>"27",
            "28"=>"28",
            "29"=>"29",
            "30"=>"30",
            "31"=>"31"
    );

    $html = "<select name='{$days}'>";
    if(!empty($top_days)){
        foreach($top_days as $value){
            if(array_key_exists($value, $days)){
                $html .="<option value='{$value}'>{$days[$value]}</option>";
            }
        }
        $html .="<option>----------</option>";
    }
    foreach($days as $key => $day){
        $html .="<option value='{$key}'>{$day}</option>";
    }
    $html .="</select>";
    return $html;

}

function year_dropdown($year="year", $top_years=array()) {
    $years = array(
            "choose"=>"Year",
            "----------",
            "1997"=>"1997",
            "1996"=>"1996",
            "1995"=>"1995",
            "1994"=>"1994",
            "1993"=>"1993",
            "1992"=>"1992",
            "1991"=>"1991",
            "1990"=>"1990",
            "1989"=>"1989",
            "1988"=>"1988",
            "1987"=>"1987",
            "1986"=>"1986",
            "1985"=>"1985",
            "1984"=>"1984",
            "1983"=>"1983",
            "1982"=>"1982",
            "1981"=>"1981",
            "1980"=>"1980",
            "1979"=>"1979",
            "1978"=>"1978",
            "1977"=>"1977",
            "1976"=>"1976",
            "1975"=>"1975",
            "1974"=>"1974",
            "1973"=>"1973",
            "1972"=>"1972",
            "1971"=>"1971",
            "1970"=>"1970",
            "1969"=>"1969",
            "1968"=>"1968",
            "1967"=>"1967",
            "1966"=>"1966",
            "1965"=>"1965",
            "1964"=>"1964",
            "1963"=>"1963",
            "1962"=>"1962",
            "1961"=>"1961",
            "1960"=>"1960",
            "1959"=>"1959",
            "1959"=>"1959",
            "1958"=>"1958",
            "1957"=>"1957",
            "1956"=>"1956",
            "1955"=>"1955",
            "1954"=>"1954",
            "1953"=>"1953",
            "1953"=>"1953",
            "1952"=>"1952",
            "1951"=>"1951",
            "1950"=>"1950",
            "1949"=>"1949",
            "1948"=>"1948",
            "1947"=>"1947",
            "1946"=>"1946",
            "1945"=>"1945",
            "1944"=>"1944",
            "1943"=>"1943",
            "1942"=>"1942",
            "1941"=>"1941",
            "1940"=>"1940",
            "1939"=>"1939",
            "1938"=>"1938",
            "1937"=>"1937",
            "1936"=>"1936",
            "1935"=>"1935",
            "1934"=>"1934",
            "1933"=>"1933",
            "1932"=>"1932",
            "1931"=>"1931",
            "1930"=>"1930"

    );

    $html = "<select name='{$years}'>";
    if(!empty($top_years)){
        foreach($top_years as $value){
            if(array_key_exists($value, $years)){
                $html .="<option value='{$value}'>{$years[$value]}</option>";
            }
        }
        $html .="<option>----------</option>";
    }
    foreach($years as $key => $year){
        $html .="<option value='{$key}'>{$year}</option>";
    }
    $html .="</select>";
    return $html;

}
```

Here is the portion of it on my model inside the update query: ****EDIT****

$birthdate = $this->input->post('month') . "/" . $this->input->post('day') ."/" .$this->input->post('year');'birthday' => $this->input->post($birthdate),

Here it is displayed on my view: ****EDIT****

```
echo month_dropdown('month')." ".day_dropdown('day'). " ".year_dropdown('year');
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in functions.

I would suggest that in **$top_month**,instead of sending an array, better send the selected value.

And i think in **$month** you are sending the **name of select box** so better use it instead of using **$months**.

Also i have made the code to show the selected value in select box.

```
function month_dropdown($month="month", $top_month='' ) {

   $months = array(
        "choose"=>"Month",
        "Jan"=>"Jan",
        "Feb"=>"Feb",
        "Mar"=>"Mar",
        "Apr"=>"Apr",
        "May"=>"May",
        "Jun"=>"Jun",
        "Jul"=>"Jul",
        "Aug"=>"Aug",
        "Sep"=>"Sep",
        "Oct"=>"Oct",
        "Nov"=>"Nov",
        "Dec"=>"Dec"
  );

  $html = "<select name='{$month}'>";

  foreach($months as $key => $month){

      $selected = "";
      //this will match for selected value and set the selected attribute
      if( $key == $top_month ) {
          $selected = "selected='selected'";
      }
      $html .="<option value='{$key}' $selected>{$month}</option>";
  }
  $html .="</select>";
  return $html;

}

function day_dropdown($day="day", $top_days="") {
   $days = array(
        "choose"=>"Day",
        "1"=>"1",
        "2"=>"2",
        "3"=>"3",
        "4"=>"4",
        "5"=>"5",
        "6"=>"6",
        "7"=>"7",
        "8"=>"8",
        "9"=>"9",
        "10"=>"10",
        "11"=>"11",
        "12"=>"12",
        "13"=>"13",
        "14"=>"14",
        "15"=>"15",
        "16"=>"16",
        "17"=>"17",
        "18"=>"18",
        "19"=>"19",
        "20"=>"20",
        "21"=>"21",
        "22"=>"22",
        "23"=>"23",
        "24"=>"24",
        "25"=>"25",
        "26"=>"26",
        "27"=>"27",
        "28"=>"28",
        "29"=>"29",
        "30"=>"30",
        "31"=>"31"
   );

   $html = "<select name='{$day}'>";

   foreach($days as $key => $day){
      $selected = "";
      if( $key == $top_days ) {
          $selected = "selected='selected'";
      }

      $html .="<option value='{$key}' $selected >{$day}</option>";
   }
   $html .="</select>";
   return $html;

}

function year_dropdown($year="year", $top_years='') {
   $years = array(
        "choose"=>"Year",
        "1997"=>"1997",
        "1996"=>"1996",
        "1995"=>"1995",
        "1994"=>"1994",
        "1993"=>"1993",
        "1992"=>"1992",
        "1991"=>"1991",
        "1990"=>"1990",
        "1989"=>"1989",
        "1988"=>"1988",
        "1987"=>"1987",
        "1986"=>"1986",
        "1985"=>"1985",
        "1984"=>"1984",
        "1983"=>"1983",
        "1982"=>"1982",
        "1981"=>"1981",
        "1980"=>"1980",
        "1979"=>"1979",
        "1978"=>"1978",
        "1977"=>"1977",
        "1976"=>"1976",
        "1975"=>"1975",
        "1974"=>"1974",
        "1973"=>"1973",
        "1972"=>"1972",
        "1971"=>"1971",
        "1970"=>"1970",
        "1969"=>"1969",
        "1968"=>"1968",
        "1967"=>"1967",
        "1966"=>"1966",
        "1965"=>"1965",
        "1964"=>"1964",
        "1963"=>"1963",
        "1962"=>"1962",
        "1961"=>"1961",
        "1960"=>"1960",
        "1959"=>"1959",
        "1959"=>"1959",
        "1958"=>"1958",
        "1957"=>"1957",
        "1956"=>"1956",
        "1955"=>"1955",
        "1954"=>"1954",
        "1953"=>"1953",
        "1953"=>"1953",
        "1952"=>"1952",
        "1951"=>"1951",
        "1950"=>"1950",
        "1949"=>"1949",
        "1948"=>"1948",
        "1947"=>"1947",
        "1946"=>"1946",
        "1945"=>"1945",
        "1944"=>"1944",
        "1943"=>"1943",
        "1942"=>"1942",
        "1941"=>"1941",
        "1940"=>"1940",
        "1939"=>"1939",
        "1938"=>"1938",
        "1937"=>"1937",
        "1936"=>"1936",
        "1935"=>"1935",
        "1934"=>"1934",
        "1933"=>"1933",
        "1932"=>"1932",
        "1931"=>"1931",
        "1930"=>"1930"

   );

   $html = "<select name='{$year}'>";

   foreach($years as $key => $year){

      $selected = "";
      if( $key == $top_years ) {
          $selected = "selected='selected'";
      }

     $html .="<option value='{$key}' $selected >{$year}</option>";
   }
   $html .="</select>";
   return $html;

 }
```

That will i think resolve your doubts. If anything else, let me know.

Comment: This is a good start, however I am not sure how to mesh this properly with what I have on view and controller. aka what are the proper values to use in my view and controller. thanks for the help.

Comment: this actually makes the most sense to me, however it's inserting 0000-00-00

Comment: I meant to say this makes sense: echo month_dropdown('birthday', $month)." ".day_dropdown('birthday', $day). " ".year_dropdown('birthday', $year); or echo month_dropdown('birthday')." ".day_dropdown('birthday'). " ".year_dropdown('birthday');